# How can I implement a "promise like" thread-synchronization system in Java 7?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, java-7

I have a static method for obtaining a global object:

```
public static Application getApplication() {
    // ...
}
```

The `Application` instance takes time to create due to I/O, so we create it in a separate thread. During this time, it may happen that other threads attempt to call `getApplication()`. The behavior I want is for those threads to block until the global `Application` instance has been created. I basically want something with this structure:

```
private static Application application;
private static PromiseLikeLock lock = new PromiseLikeLock();

public static Application getApplication() {
    lock.await();
    return application;
}

// In thread:
application = new Application();
lock.release();
```

With the following behavior:

1. The `lock` object is a state machine which is either *locked* or *released*. It starts locked.
2. When a thread hits a call to `lock.wait()`, if the lock is released it proceeds as normal, otherwise it blocks.
3. When `lock.release()` is called, the lock becomes released and all threads blocking on a call to `wait()` unblock.

Comment: @pdem Right, but they don't fit my conditions. They violate point (2).

Comment: ok, and why java7? I would suggest CompletableFuture which is from java 8, and I tend to migrate all my application to java11

Comment: @pdem Hardware-imposed (Android on specialized hardware).

Comment: Actually, I'm going to rephrase the question - my implementation using wait and notify isn't working, so I'd be happy with an answer suggesting a home-rolled implementation.

Comment: Do you have to recreate the "Application" each time or is it a create once, then it's available for however long the app is open?

Comment: @Tschallacka It's created once.

Comment: @JackM how long does it take for the Application to be initialized? Can't you implement a loading screen when the Application is being initialized? 30 seconds would be acceptable if there's a progress bar.

Comment: @JackM you should consider spending some time reading about package `java.util.concurrent`

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do it .... using Java 7 APIs.

```
FutureTask<Application> ft =
       new FutureTask<>(new Callable<Application>() {
                             public Application call() {
                                  return new Application();
                             }});
new Thread(ft).start();

// Somewhere else / later on
Application app = ft.get();
```

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) for `FutureTask` describes it as follows:

> A cancellable asynchronous computation. This class provides a base implementation of `Future`, with methods to start and cancel a computation, query to see if the computation is complete, and retrieve the result of the computation. The result can only be retrieved when the computation has completed; the `get` methods will block if the computation has not yet completed. ....
>
> A `FutureTask` can be used to wrap a `Callable` or `Runnable` object. Because `FutureTask` implements `Runnable`, a `FutureTask` can be submitted to an `Executor` for execution.

And you can pass it to a single-use `Thread` too.

---

But frankly you shouldn't be writing new code for Java 7.  The above is cleaner if you use Java 8 language features; e.g. `Application::new`

Answer (score 1):

This looks much like the singleton pattern, which can be implemented using an enum with a single value:

```
enum Application{
  INSTANCE;


  private Application(){
    //initialize
  }
  //other methods/fields can go here...
}
```

The initialization will occur when the class is first loaded. The classloader guarantees thread safety, i.e. it will call the constructor only once and other classes accessing Application.INSTANCE will be blocked until it's fully loaded.

The difference between this and the FutureTask solution is that there is no separate thread launched, the initialization is invoked in the first thread that actually uses it.

Comment: Woah. So declaring it as an enum rather than a class changes the way the runtime handles it?

Comment: Well, if you would declare it as a normal class with a 'static initialization block', it would handle it more or less the same as an enum, but an enum is a much clearer syntax than a static initialization block, especially if you only need one instance of it.